# ReactiveCocoa Ambiguous reference to member RACSignal

Tags: swift, racsignal, reactive-cocoa-4

I'm trying to return an `RACSignal` that I can use in my objective-c code, I've tried various ways. EX:

```
@objc
    class func getPosts() -> RACSignal {
        let (signal, observer) = Signal<String, NSError>.pipe()
        return signal.toRACSignal()
    }
```

Also this way.

```
@objc
    class func getPosts() -> RACSignal {
        return SignalProducer {
            observer, disposable in
        }.toRACSignal()
    }
```

But `XCode` always says the same:

> ambiguous reference to member toRACSignal

My podfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Bebler' do
    pod 'ComponentKit', '= 0.14'
    pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '~> 4.1.0'
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.1'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.3'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
    pod 'KeychainSwift', '~> 3.0'
end
```

I have Xcode version 7.3

also tried this:

```
@objc
    class func getPosts() -> RACSignal {
        let signalProducer: SignalProducer<String, NSError> =  SignalProducer {
            observer, disposable in
            }
        return signalProducer.toRACSignal()
    }
```

same result.

Comment: Can it be caused by the two same func `getPosts` ?

Comment: It's not at same time, those are the ways I tried, seems that I put them in the same pre.

Answer (score 0):

you may try it like this: (optionals)

```
@objc
class func getPosts() -> RACSignal? {
    if let (signal, observer) = Signal<String, NSError>.pipe() as? Signal! {
      return signal.toRACSignal()
    }
    return nil
}
```